# How to get the font name for the content displayed in CK Editor in Visualforce page ?

Tags: visualforce, richtextarea, font

I have two Visualforce pages and I am using CK editor to display the Rich Text Area field in these Visualforce pages. One VF page is for creating template(Rich Text Area Content) and the other one is for using that pre existing template created in 1st VF page and add some more content to that template.  The whole text content that is being inserted in 1st VF page's Rich Text Area field would be of only one particular font (eg: Georgia).

Is there a way to get the font-name of that particular content that is being displayed in CK Editor in 2nd VF page? 
The font that is set can be anything that is available in MS Word's font list and not just limited to the list of fonts available in CK Editor fonts dropdown list because the user usually copy pastes the content from MS Word in 1st VF page while creating a template.

Also is there a way to restrict a user in CK Editor to use that same font (something like locking font to the one that is used while creating original content in 1st VF page) if he is trying to add some more content to this CK Editor (Rich Text area) field in 2nd VF page.

your help would be appreciated...

Thanks,
Win4frndz